# How can I calculate Entropy of picture in two directions(Horizental and vertical)?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, entropy

I need to calculate Entropy of picture in two directions(Horizental and vertical)?
How can I implement it on matlab?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean by horizontal and vertical entropy? I'm used to calculating the entropy for the entire image.

Comment: Along with that is the input image expected to be a greyscale or rgb/colour image?

Comment: @MichaelTr7 Hello , My image is gray scale.I read it on the paper that used Entropy in 2 directions  as a feature .

Comment: @MichaelTr7 this is a doi of that article:    https://doi.org/10.1016/j.anres.2017.12.002

Comment: from my brief skim it seems that there is only a single equation for entropy in this article which is equation (5).

Comment: There is some documentation that goes over GLCM (Gray-Level Co-Occurrence) and deriving energy from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be edited: Some possibly useful information.

## Finding Horizontal and Vertical Energy for an Image using GLCM (Gray-Level Co-Occurrence Matrices)

Based on the document posted in the comment related to texture analysis. To find the horizontal and vertical energy for an image the statistics can be pulled from the GLCM (Gray-Level Co-Occurrence Matrix), specifically in this case the `Energy` property. The direction of the nearest neighbour/values to check between the relationship. I would recommend looking more in-depth into all the properties of these functions due to my limited knowledge/experience using them.

The direction/offset is a vector defined as:
[Vertical_Direction Horizontal_Direction]

### Useful Related MATLAB Documentation:

[MATLAB Documentation: Create gray-level co-occurrence matrix from image](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/graycomatrix.html)

[MATLAB Documentation: Texture Analysis Using the Gray-Level Co-Occurrence Matrix (GLCM)](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/texture-analysis-using-the-gray-level-co-occurrence-matrix-glcm.html)

### Script:

```
%Creating the sample image and plotting%
Sample_Image = imread("Greyscale_Image.png");

%Calculating the Gray-Level Co-Occurence Matrices%
Horizontal_Offset = [0 1];
Vertical_Offset = [1 0];

Horizontal_GLCM = graycomatrix(Sample_Image, 'offset', Horizontal_Offset, 'Symmetric', true);
Vertical_GLCM = graycomatrix(Sample_Image, 'offset', Vertical_Offset, 'Symmetric', true);

Horizontal_Statistics = graycoprops(Horizontal_GLCM);
Horizontal_Statistics.Energy

Vertical_Statistics = graycoprops(Vertical_GLCM);
Vertical_Statistics.Energy
```

Interestingly the entropy of the `Horizontal_GLCM` and `Vertical_GLCM` are equal

```
entropy(Horizontal_GLCM)
entropy(Vertical_GLCM)
```

## Finding Entropy for an Image (Grayscale/Greyscale)

### Preface:

Entropy for images and strings is typically defined in the following form:
[image: Entropy Equations]
[image: Probability Equation]

Where, `pi` is the entropy probability for a given pixel intensity `I` and `H(s)` is the entropy for the signal/image. The probability is the frequency of the pixel intensity/number of pixels. An example of this may include:

[image: Sample Greyscale Image]

**Number of Pixels = 8**

Pixel Intensity: **20**  → Frequency = `1` → Probability = `1/8` → Entropy Term = -(`1/8`)×log2(`1/8`)
Pixel Intensity: **80**  → Frequency = `3` → Probability = `3/8` → Entropy Term = -(`3/8`)×log2(`3/8`)
Pixel Intensity: **120** → Frequency = `3` → Probability = `3/8` → Entropy Term = -(`3/8`)×log2(`3/8`)
Pixel Intensity: **160** → Frequency = `1` → Probability = `1/8` → Entropy Term = -(`1/8`)×log2(`1/8`)

**Entropy of Image:**

H(s) = [-(`1/8`)×log2(`1/8`)] + [-(`3/8`)×log2(`3/8`)] + [-(`3/8`)×log2(`3/8`)] + [-(`1/8`)×log2(`1/8`)]

H(s) ≈ 1.811278 (2-bits required to encode the image based on source coding)

### Scripts:

### Method 1: Using the `entropy()` Function

The `entropy()` function returns the entropy for the image and sets the lower bound for the number of bits required to encode the image. More specifically `Number_Of_Bits_Required = ceil(entropy(image))`.

```
%Creating the sample image and plotting%
Sample_Image = uint8([20 80 80 80; 120 120 120 160]);
imshow(Sample_Image,'InitialMagnification',1500);
title("Test Image");
set(gcf, 'Position',  [100, 100, 500, 400]);
axis on
xlabel('X-Axis'); ylabel('Y-Axis');

Image_Entropy = entropy(Sample_Image);
```

### Method 2: Calculating Using Loops

Uses a loop to go through all the unique pixel intensities. Counts the occurrences by using a conditionally set logical matrix and taking the sum of that matrix. The probability is then found by diving the occurrences by the number of pixels. The `log2()` of the probability is then taken and added to the variable `Calculated_Entropy` which will accumulate/add up all the entropy terms corresponding to each specific probability.

```
%Creating the sample image and plotting%
Sample_Image = uint8([20 80 80 80; 120 120 120 160]);
imshow(Sample_Image,'InitialMagnification',1500);
title("Test Image");
set(gcf, 'Position',  [100, 100, 500, 400]);
axis on
xlabel('X-Axis'); ylabel('Y-Axis');

%Finding the image dimensions%
[Image_Height,Image_Width] = size(Sample_Image);
Number_Of_Pixels = Image_Height*Image_Width;

%Evaluating the unique intensity values%
Unique_Intensities = unique(Sample_Image);

%Initializing variables for later use%
Number_Of_Unique_Intensities = length(Unique_Intensities);
Probabilities = zeros(Number_Of_Unique_Intensities,1);
Calculated_Entropy = 0;

%Scanning through the unique intensities and evaluating the probabilities%
for Intensity_Index = 1: Number_Of_Unique_Intensities

    %Grabbing a unique intensity value%
    Intensity_Value = Unique_Intensities(Intensity_Index,1);  
    
        %Evaluating the frequency of the unique intensity value%
        Check_Array = (Sample_Image == Intensity_Value);
        Probabilities(Intensity_Index,1) = sum(Check_Array,'all')/Number_Of_Pixels;
        Calculated_Entropy = -Probabilities(Intensity_Index,1)*log2(Probabilities(Intensity_Index,1))+Calculated_Entropy;
        
end

Image_Entropy = entropy(Sample_Image);

fprintf("Calculated entropy: %f\n",Calculated_Entropy);
fprintf("Using the entropy function: %f\n",Image_Entropy);
```

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**